# Dropkick - Array of selects issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have encountered a following problem while using dropkick plugin for jQuery. When I add a `select`field and give it a name with square brackets, i.e `orders[]`, the whole select item dissappears. I don't know what to do, I need to use array of selects and I'd like to keep on using dropkick :)

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Cheers :)

Comment: Can you add samples of your code to see where the error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely down to the plugin not correctly handling the square brackets within the name of your select.

I'll confirm this shortly, however I assume it is trying to select another element or elements using the `name` of your select, which includes square brackets.

As a result, jQuery will think your trying to find a select with a parameter.

**Update**

As promised, this is the error I get when trying to replicate your problem:

[image: Error]

This is because on line 82, it is trying to get the ID or Name.

**A solution, set a unique ID for each of your select elements and it should avoid using the Name attribute.**

See http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/mw3Xg/ for an example which has a name of `orders[]`